# Aspectj: Pointcut no longer works when declared in aop.xml ( LTW)

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, pointcut

I m trying to define my aspect as a concrete-aspect to be able to define pointcuts in aop.xml without compiling the code. I m using LTW.

when I define my poincut exp in the aspect class itself and define the aspect as a simple aspect (  ), it works fine. however, when I declare the aspect as a concrete-aspect and define the pointcut in aop.xml. the aspect is not working anymore... and it doesn't hit the breakpoint inside my advise anymore...

Here is the code with / without concrete-aspects:

Without concrete aspects ( WORKS FINE):

```
public abstract aspect AbstractAspect {
    protected abstract pointcut publicMethod();
}

public aspect MethodExecutionTimeAspect extends AbstractAspect {
    public pointcut publicMethod() : execution(public * com.proj.package..*());
    Object around() : publicMethod() {
        .....
        Object ret = proceed();
        ....
   }
}
```

and the aop.xml

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
    <aspect  name="com.proj.packae.aspectj.MethodExecutionTimeAspect"/> 
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose">
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

With Concrete aspects ( DOESN'T WORK)

```
public abstract aspect AbstractAspect {
    protected abstract pointcut publicMethod();
}

public aspect MethodExecutionTimeAspect extends AbstractAspect {
    public pointcut publicMethod() : execution(public * com.proj.package..*());
    Object around() : publicMethod() {
        .....
        Object ret = proceed();
        ....
   }
}
```

aop.xml

```
  <aspectj>
<aspects>

     <concrete-aspect name="com.proj.package.MethodExecutionTimeAspect" extends="com.project.package.aspectj.AbstractAspect">
        <pointcut name="publicMethod" expression="execution(public * com.proj.package..*())" />
    </concrete-aspect>

</aspects>

<weaver options="-verbose">

</weaver>
```

I m using aspectj 1.6 jars.

When I don't use concret-aspects, this the following logs

```
[WebappClassLoader@7f62cbb2] info register aspect com.project.package.aspectj.MethodExecutionTimeAspect
```

and when I use concrete-aspects, I see the following logs:

```
[WebappClassLoader@393e11ac] info define aspect com.project.package.aspectj.MethodExecutionTimeAspect
```

No errors are shown on the log, it just look like the concret aspects is not registered.

Please advise.

Comment: I think you forgot to add a 'javaagent' option to your java command executing the JVM. It's like '-javaagent=...aspectjweaver.jar'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made several errors:

- When using `<concrete-aspect>`, the concrete pointcut should just be in your *aop.xml*, not in your code. Maybe it was a copy & paste error, but in your example it looks as if the concrete pointcut was defined twice: in code and in XML.
- When concretising an abstract aspect, the abstract aspect must already contain the advice you want to map to the concrete pointcut. It cannot be overridden via XML or via a combination of code and XML.

Look at my own example, quite similar to yours:

**Sample application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.say("Hello world!");
        app.add(11, 22);
    }

    private int add(int i, int j) { return i + j; }
    public void say(String message) { System.out.println(message); }
}
```

As you can see, there are two public methods (one static, one non-static) and a private method. I did this so as to test if the concrete pointcut later really only catches the public ones.

**Abstract aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspectj;

public abstract aspect AbstractAspect {
    protected abstract pointcut publicMethod();

    Object around() : publicMethod() {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

**aop.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <concrete-aspect
            name="de.scrum_master.aspectj.ConcreteAspect"
            extends="de.scrum_master.aspectj.AbstractAspect"
        >
            <pointcut
                name="publicMethod"
                expression="execution(public * de.scrum_master..*(..))"
            />
        </concrete-aspect>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

**Application output when using LTW:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.say(String))
Hello world!
```

Comment: I tried this. its not working.. do I need to do any configuration (or) buildpath (or) any other setup?

Comment: @kriegaex Can you please answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693552/aspectj-aop-ltw-not-working-with-dynamic-loading-of-javaagent) ?