# AspectJ AOP LTW not working with dynamic loading of javaagent

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspect, load-time-weaving

[Here is my sample non-working project](https://github.com/pankajsinghal/aop-example).

It contains 2 modules:

- **aop-lib** - Aspects used as lib. It contains the following classes

  1. **Wrap.java** - It's the annotation used to attach advice
  2. **WrapDef.java** - It is the definition of the above mentioned `Wrap` annotation.
- **aop-app** - Uses the above aspect lib

  1. **DynamicLoad.java** - class to load javaagent dynamically
  2. **Main.java** - Main class which uses `Wrap` annotation.

Dir structure is as follows:

```
.
├── README.md
├── aop-app
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── aop
│                       └── app
│                           ├── DynamicLoad.java
│                           └── Main.java
└── aop-lib
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        └── main
            └── java
                └── com
                    └── aop
                        └── app
                            └── lib
                                ├── Wrap.java
                                └── WrapDef.java
```

I'm trying to use the aspect lib `aop-lib` (an AOP advice lib) inside `aop-app` through Load Time Weaving (LTW) by dynamically loading the javaagent as mentioned in the [official docs](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-187.html). But it's not working.

Following are the contents of [Wrap.java](https://github.com/pankajsinghal/aop-ltw/blob/master/aop-lib/src/main/java/com/aop/app/lib/Wrap.java)

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Wrap { }
```

Following are the contents of [WrapDef.java](https://github.com/pankajsinghal/aop-ltw/blob/master/aop-lib/src/main/java/com/aop/app/lib/WrapDef.java)

```
@Aspect
public class WrapDef {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WrapDef.class);

    public static boolean loaded = false;

    @Around("@annotation( wrapAnnotation ) && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object processSystemRequest(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Wrap wrapAnnotation)
            throws Throwable {
        logger.debug("before wrap");
        Object o = pjp.proceed();
        logger.debug("after wrap");
        return o;
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("Loading");
        WrapDef.loaded = true;
    }
    public static void reportLoaded() {
        System.out.println("loaded : " + loaded);
    }
}
```

Following are the contents of [Main.java](https://github.com/pankajsinghal/aop-ltw/blob/master/aop-app/src/main/java/com/aop/app/Main.java):

```
public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    @Wrap
    public void myFunc(){
        logger.debug("inside myFunc");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        boolean dynamicLoad = Boolean.getBoolean("dynamicLoad");
        if(dynamicLoad){
            Main.isAdviceClassLoaded();           //To see if WrapDef.java is loaded or not.
            if(!DynamicLoad.isAspectJAgentLoaded()) {
                logger.error("AspectJ Not Loaded. Existing.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            Main.isAdviceClassLoaded();           //To see if WrapDef.java is loaded or not.
        }

        new Main().myFunc();
    }

    private static void isAdviceClassLoaded() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        java.lang.reflect.Method m = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("findLoadedClass", String.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Object test1 = m.invoke(cl, "com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef");
        boolean loaded = test1 != null;
        System.out.println("com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef Loaded : " + loaded);
    }

}
```

With `javaagent` as cmd line arg, it works perfectly fine:

```
$ java -javaagent:deploy/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar -classpath aop-app-1.0.jar:deploy/lib/* com.aop.app.Main
14:02:45.384 [main] DEBUG com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef - before wrap
14:02:45.391 [main] DEBUG com.aop.app.Main - inside myFunc
14:02:45.391 [main] DEBUG com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef - after wrap
```

But, with Dynamic loading of `javaagent`, it gives the following output:

```
$ java -DdynamicLoad=true -DAGENT_PATH=deploy/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar -classpath aop-app-1.0.jar:deploy/lib/* com.aop.app.Main
com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef Loaded : false                   //The WrapDef is NOT loaded before JAVAAGENT is Loaded - which is correct
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AspectJ weaving agent was neither started via '-javaagent' (preMain) nor attached via 'VirtualMachine.loadAgent' (agentMain)
loading javaAgent deploy/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar
loaded javaAgent deploy/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar      //The JAVAAGENT is Dynamically Loaded - which is correct
com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef Loaded : false                   //The WrapDef is STILL NOT loaded even AFTER JAVAAGENT is Loaded - THIS IS THE ISSUE
15:53:08.543 [main] DEBUG com.aop.app.Main - inside myFunc
```

The [official docs](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-187.html) does say that `any classes loaded before attachment will not be woven`. But, on the contrary as you can see in the above output, the `WrapDef` class is not loaded at all.

Also, note that I'm using `aspectj-maven-plugin` in my [aop-lib/pom.xml](https://github.com/pankajsinghal/aop-ltw/blob/master/aop-lib/pom.xml), with the following options:

```
<outxml>true</outxml>                           //creates META-INF/aop-ajc.xml
<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>             //supposed to create <weaver options="-showWeaveInfo"/> BUT DOES NOT WORK
<verbose>true</verbose>                         //supposed to create <weaver options="-verbose"/> BUT DOES NOT WORK
```

So, it creates `META-INF/aop-ajc.xml` inside `aop-lib-1.0.jar` with the following content:

```
<aspectj>
<aspects>
<aspect name="com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef"/>
</aspects>
</aspectj>
```

but the other tags corresponding to `showWeaveInfo` & `verbose` are not created in `META-INF/aop-ajc.xml`. This is another thing that is not working here.

If you require any other info - I shall provide it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is quite simple: You are testing the weaving agent directly in class `Main` which is already loaded **before** you attach that very agent from that class. So you have to avoid classes which you like to be woven to be loaded too early. I suggest you put method `myFunc()` (horrible name, by the way) into another class. How about that?

```
package com.aop.app;

import com.aop.app.lib.Wrap;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Application {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  @Wrap
  public void myFunc(){
    logger.debug("inside myFunc");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().myFunc();
  }
}
```

Then in the last line of `Main.main(..)` you start the actual application you want woven:

```java
Application.main(null);
```

This will yield the following output:

```
com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef Loaded : false
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AspectJ weaving agent was neither started via '-javaagent' (preMain) nor attached via 'VirtualMachine.loadAgent' (agentMain)
loading javaAgent aop-app/target/deploy/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar
loaded javaAgent aop-app/target/deploy/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar
com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef Loaded : false
Loading
07:56:21.703 [main] DEBUG com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef - before wrap
07:56:21.716 [main] DEBUG com.aop.app.Application - inside myFunc
07:56:21.716 [main] DEBUG com.aop.app.lib.WrapDef - after wrap
```

P.S.: Do you really think it is easier for users of your aspect library to specify two properties on the JVM command line instead of just using `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectweaver.jar`? Anyway, you probably have your reasons to use dynamic weaver attachment. In a way I am kind of happy that someone uses the functionality I added to AspectJ myself a while ago. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you also answer why `<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>` doesn't create a `<weaver options="-showWeaveInfo"/>` tag in aop.xml & what can I do to make it happen?

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble using `com.sun.tools.jar` because it's not loaded in jre classpath on server. I've asked a question about it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707812/adding-com-sun-tools-jar-in-classpath-of-jar . Can you help me here also?

Comment: Question 1: AspectJ Maven is for compile-time weaving, it has no influence whatsoever on LTW. You have to customise your _aop.xml_ the way you want it to, e.g. you could use Maven Resources plugin or whatever seems appropriate. It would be easier to just provide the complete file as a resource and not use `<outxml>` at all if you are not happy with the default file. Question 2: You need a JDK in order to pull off that dynamic weaver attachment trick, not just a JRE. I still recommend using the standard Java agent mechanism instead of this magic (even though I sort of invented it myself).

Comment: I'm using jdk itself, and not jre (I've mentioned that in the question I linked). Even then it is not picking the jar from inside of `lib/` folder. I've also mentioned the command I use to run the java project i.e. `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java`

Comment: Then good luck to you for the other question. Here it is out of scope. It is a classpath issue, I am sure you will sort it out. P.S.: And you still don't believe me you should use the Java agent from the command line in order to save yourself trouble, do you? You'd still rather add other command line switches, fiddle with the JDK classpath etc. instead of just relying on JRE and established Java agent mechanism. You want it, now solve it.

Comment: Yeah, well I didn't wanna give up without trying. I think I'll settle with your advice eventually