# The type "com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert" is not accessible

Tags: java

Could you please help me to understand why this type not accessible is?

Versions:

Eclips / Photon Release (4.8.0)

selenium-java-3.14.0

JavaSE-10

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hkoq.png)

Comment: More context please

Comment: When you're using Java 9 or greater you have no access to com.sun packages any more, they are not exposed by the new modular jdk

Comment: provide us more code please

Comment: You shouldn't be using that `Assert` class in your code.  My bet is that you should be using `Assert` from the JUnit APIs.

Comment: Do not use `com.sun.*` classes. They are an internal part of the JDK, are undocumented and can change or disappear without warning in any new JDK version.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using that `Assert` class in your code. It is internal to the Java compiler, and not intended for reuse.

There have been warnings in the Sun / Oracle documentation for many years that user code should not depend on the internal `com.sun.*` APIs.  Starting with Java 9, access to these and other internal APIs have been closed off by the module system.   It is possible to allow the access ... but you shouldn't if you have an alternative.

- These APIs are undocumented, and may be withdrawn without any notice, causing portability problems when you upgrade your JVM to a newer release.
- Some Java implementations don't implement these APIs, leading to portability problems when you try to use a JVM from a different vendor.

My bet is that you *should* be using `Assert` from the JUnit APIs, and that you have picked up the bogus `import` by accepting an (incorrect) auto-correction suggested by your IDE.

The best solution is to change your code to use `org.junit.Assert` or something equivalent.