# Any guideline for aspectj LTW using custom class loader

Tags: java, aspectj

I want to use the aspectj with the LTW, and I don't want to use the agent

I did some search, and found little, only in below article, mentioned something https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html, "Custom class loader
A public interface is provided to allow a user written class loader to instantiate a weaver and weave classes after loading and before defining them in the JVM. This enables load-time weaving to be supported in environments where no weaving agent is available. It also allows the user to explicitly restrict by class loader which classes can be woven. For more information, see aj and the API documentation and source for WeavingURLClassLoader and WeavingAdapter."

Is there any guideline for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to implement a custom classloader if not strictly necessary.

Newer versions of [AspectJ since 1.8.7](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-187.html) can dynamically start the load-time weaver if it is on the classpath, even if the JVM is not started as a Java Agent. (I know because I implemented this little feature myself.) Please read the description and be aware of the main caveat: It only works for classes loaded **after** your own code has attached the weaver, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51699432/1082681) to someone who tripped over this issue.